# Storing the contents of a global array in assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, global

I've been struggling to get my code to work for the last couple of days. It's purpose is to store a passed parameter into a GLOBAL array. The parameter is passed through a different file in C code but that's not the issue i'm having. So whenever I try to store the value into the location of the array i keep getting a segmentation fault! I understand that they are caused because i'm trying to access an illegal address but I seriously can't think of how to fix this issue. If someone could help me I would be very grateful! My assembly code is below

```
define(stackSize,5)
define(true,1)
define(false,0)

       .data                                            //for global variables
        .bss
        .global     stack_arr
stack_arr: .skip        5 * 4                   //5 long array of ints

        .data
        .global     top
top:    .word   -1                      // global word =-1
        .text
        .balign 4
        .global main
main:
            stp x29, x30, [sp,-16]!                 //allocate stack memeory
            mov x29, sp                             //have sp point to x29

            mov w9, w0                          //w9 = passed parameter 

            bl stackFull                                // check if stackFull
            mov w10,  w0                            //w10=result of stackFull
            cmp w10, true
            //b.eq printOverflow                    //if stackFull returns true print
            //othersise,

            adrp x11, top
            add x11, x11, :lo12:top                 // move top to x11
            ldr x12, [x11]
            add x12, x12, 1                         //++top

            adrp x13, stack_arr
            add x13, x13, :lo12:stack_arr       // move stack address to x13


            str w9, [x13, x12, lsl 2]                   //store

            ldp x29, x30, [sp], 16 
            ret
```

Comment: As a courtesy, if you see your post come out with broken formatting, click the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49582484/edit) and fix it by using the code formatting button on the toolbar. Also, always remember to add architecture tag. As to your problem, learn to use a debugger to at least pinpoint the fault.

Comment: I did. The fault is in the 'str' part. Everything works fine up till then.

Comment: If you know it's the `str` then you can deduce that either `x14` or `x12` are wrong. So check their value in the debugger then work backwards to see how the wrong value got there. Hint: It's unclear what you want to achieve with `ldr  x14, [x13] ` ... since `x13` has the address of `stack_arr` that will fetch the first word from there and that is initially zero, hence a null pointer access.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code and removed the ldr sections accessing stack_arr through x13. I still seem to be getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: However since `top` is in fact a variable, you **do** want to load its value.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this as well but still have the same issue.

Comment: That about looks correct, you just have to use your debugger to examine what is still wrong.